# getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new  in angularJS. i am creating registration task. here if i am sending individual attribute. getting success message. but i am try to send object as json.

but getting below error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Client side code

```
function registration(user) {
            var employee={
                    name:user.firstName+" "+user.lastName,
                    email:user.emailAddress,
                    password:user.password
            };
            var data = JSON.stringify(employee);
            $http.post('http://localhost:8080/AngularJSSpring/ajax/register', data
            ).success(
                    function(data, status) {
                        defer.resolve(data);
                    });
                return defer.promise;
        }
```

server side code (spring mvc)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/register", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONResponse registration(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
        System.out.println("ajax register");
        return angularView.registration(emp);

    }
```

i also try by modifiying

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/AngularJSSpring/ajax/register', employee)
```

but not working.. please help me for this

Comment: Well, you problem come from the URL or the server. Not from the client side (angular). I can't test that for you, did you check the url ? Using a REST Client for example.

Comment: Solved!!!. actually problem was from server side. "@RequestBody Employee emp" is not working. i change object to String and then converted json into Object..

Comment: Like a said, server issues. You should check how Spring works, because it is suppose to do that for you (never take the time to use it ...)

Answer (score 0):

The thing with  Spring is that, when ever you create a new **Package** which as a matter includes a **Controller class** (with **@Controller** annotation), **Request Handler** to handle your corresponding requests (ie. request made  from the client side), you will have me mention this package  as a **base-package** attribute under `<context  ....../>` tag    in **spring-servlet.xml** file .

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="Your package Name" />
```

You can find this file in

> WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml

Eventually, this would tell the **Spring's Request Handler** to include package's controller class to  search for request too.

Presuming  this is the situation you have come across, **Request handler** in your case is not able to find the associated request , even though the **@RequestMapping** method exists.

Hope this helps
Cheers